# php function not returning an array

Tags: php, function

I have the following code, sorry for the length but it saves explaining most of what i need...
the $result in the pages() function is not being returned.  When I call for it all I get is undefined variable.  Why?
What i need is to pass the $start and $display variables to the mysql query.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_records_submit'])) {
    $pages; $start; $display; $result;
    function pages($stmt) {
        //set how many records per page
        $display = 10;
        //determine how many pages there are
        if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { //already determined
            $pages = $_GET['p'];
        }
        else {
            $records = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        }
        //calculate the number of pages
        if($records > $display) { //if there are more records than will fit on one page
            $pages = ceil($records/$display); //ceil() rounds up to the nearest integer
        }
        else { //records will fit on one page
            $pages = 1;
        }
        //determine which row to start returning results from
        if(isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['S'])) { //already determined
            $start = $_GET['s'];
        }
        else {
            $start = 0;
        }
        $result = array(0=>$display, 1=>$pages , 2=>$start);
        return $result;
    }
    $searchby = $_POST['search_by'];
    $searchfor = $_POST['search_for'];
    $contact = 1;
    $i = 0;
    //set the initial query
    $query = "SELECT  client_id, title_desc, firstname, surname, house, street, town, city, county, postcode as count FROM address LEFT JOIN client USING (client_id) LEFT JOIN client_title USING (title_id) LEFT JOIN address_street USING (address_id) LEFT JOIN address_town USING (address_id) LEFT JOIN address_city USING (address_id) LEFT JOIN address_county USING (address_id) WHERE is_contact = ?";
    //depending on search terms, amend the query
    if($searchby == 'all') {
        $query .= " ORDER BY surname ASC, firstname ASC";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $contact);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        pages($stmt);
        var_dump ($result);
        foreach ($result as $var) { echo $var.' ';}
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        $query .= " ORDER BY surname ASC, firstname ASC LIMIT ?, ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iii', $contact, $start, $display);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $client_id, $stitle, $sfname, $ssname, $shouse,$sstreet, $stown, $scity, $scounty, $spostcode);      

        if($searchfor != '') {
            echo "<p>You searched under <span class=\"bold\">\"All\"</span>, therefore your search term <span class=\"bold\">\"$searchfor\"</span> has not been included.</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the `$pages; $start; $display; $result;` line?

Comment: `$result = [$display, $pages, $start];` No need for `array()` or numbers for keys.

Comment: @m59: That only works in PHP 5.4+

Comment: @RocketHazmat I always forget that :) But that's only the `[]`, right? The key things is still odd?

Comment: @m59: Yeah.  `array($display, $pages, $start)` is what you need for < PHP 5.4.  Arrays start at `0` by default.

Comment: Rocket, I was trying to make them global - nothing else was working

Comment: I tried array($display, $pages, $start) and still got nothing, I'm only running php 5.3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
pages($stmt);
```

The function `pages()` returns the array, but **this result is not being set to a variable.** Try using:

```
$result = pages($stmt);
```

And then accessing the array via the variable `$result`.

That `$result` variable that you declared up top? The reason it's not being set is because **the function `pages()` doesn't have access to it because it's not within the function's scope.**

#### Edit

As Lyth pointed out, if you don't want the function to return anything, you can modify your function as follows:

```
function pages($stmt) {
    global $result;
    // ...
    // The rest of your function
    // ...
    $result = array(0=>$display, 1=>$pages , 2=>$start);
    // Remove the 'return $result' line
}
```

Comment: Or maybe he didn't want to make a return at first.

Comment: If that's the case, he can add `global $result;` to the beginning of the `pages()` function, and then remove the `return $result;` line.

Comment: @theftprevention I'm avoiding using 'thanks' but I'm really glad there are all the stackoverflowers like you out there to stop beginners like me going mentile.

Comment: I'll avoid using "you're welcome", but if I can keep PHP from making someone else go mental, I'll gladly do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you write $pages; $start; $display; $result;? If you want to get the value of array try to use this...

```
$result = array($display, $pages , $start);
return $result;
```

You can check the array with

```
print_r ($result);
```